# delphi file search multithreading

Tags: multithreading, delphi

If i execute it like that my application wouldn't respond until find all files and them to the listbox
my question is How i can make this function multi threded to avoid unresponding situation! i am still Delphi novoice

```
procedure TfrMain.FileSearch(const PathName, FileName : string; txtToSearch : string; const InDir : boolean);
var Rec  : TSearchRec;
    Path : string;
    txt  : string;
    fh   : TextFile;
    i    : integer;
begin


Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(PathName);
if FindFirst(Path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
 try
   repeat

     AssignFile(fh, Path + Rec.Name);
     Reset(fh);
     Readln(fh,txt);

     if ContainsStr(txt, txtToSearch) then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path + Rec.Name);

   until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
 finally
   FindClose(Rec);

 end;

If not InDir then Exit;

if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
 try
   repeat
    if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..') then
     FileSearch(Path + Rec.Name, FileName, txtToSearch, True);
   until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
 finally
   FindClose(Rec);
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put the file scanning stuff into a thread and whenver work is finished send a windows message to the main form, which then updates the list box (code not tested, take it as pseudo code):

```
const 
  WM_FILESEARCH_FINISHED = WM_USER + 1;

TFileSearchThread = class (TThread)
private
  FPath       : String;
  FFileNames  : TStringList;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create (const Path : String);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property FileNames : TStrings read FFileNames;
end;

constructor TFileSearchThread.Create (const Path : String);
begin
  inherited Create (True);
  FPath := Path;
  FFileNames := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TFileSearchThread.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil (FFileNames);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFileSearchThread.Execute;  
begin
  // do your file search here, adding each file to FFileNames
  PostMessage (MainForm.Handle, WM_FILESEARCH_FINISHED, 0, 0);
end;
```

You could use it like this:

```
Thead := TFileSearchThread.Create (Path);
Thread.Start;
```

and the main form would have a message handler like this:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
  private
    procedure WMFileSearchFinished (var Msg : TMessage); message WM_FILESEARCH_FINISHED;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

procedure TMainForm.WMFileSearchFinished (var Msg : TMessage);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings (Thread.FileNames);
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `PostMessage (MainForm.Handle, WM_FILESEARCH_FINISHED, 0, 0);
` be used with `Synchronize`?

Comment: @kobik, no need to worry, the `Handle` property is read only and its reading is atomic. And it has to be different from 0 (the control would be dead and couldn't receive any message), thus the getter will never `CreateHandle` what it does when the handle is 0. The risk is the object instance itself, if you destroy `MainForm` and try to access it, you will get AV as usually. And, Emba [`uses`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22411) this too :-)

Comment: @kobik `Synchronize` uses `SendMessage` internally, which is the blocking equivalent of `PostMessage`

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2008/11/background-file-scanning-with.html) you can find an article about the background file scanner implemented with [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com).